# How to obtain the real Lie algebra form the complex Lie algebra of a Lie group?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

In this lecture [The Lie group $SL(2,C)$ and its Lie algebra $sl(2,C)$](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1D09cuFWlM&list=PLPH7f_7ZlzxTi6kS4vCmv4ZKm9u8g5yic&index=15&ab_channel=FredericSchuller) Professor Schuller goes in great detail to calculate the complex Lie algebra of the Lie group $SL(2,C)$ and obtained
$$[X_1,X_2]=2X_2 \quad [X_1,X_3]=-2X_3 \quad [X_2,X_3]=X_1$$
Now having the lie complex Lie algebra of $SL(2,C)$, is there anyway to obtain the real Lie algebra $SL(2,C)$ from this Lie algebra or we have to do the same procedure as it is done in the lecture?

Comment: there's a way to consider the real forms of the Lie algebra which will give you something nice for $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{C}) \cong \mathbb{C}\otimes_\mathbb{R}\mathfrak{so}(3,\mathbb{R})$

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you just needed to take the underlying real vector space (so the dimension doubles) and keep the same bracket. Am I confused?